# a nilpotent matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the $10\times10$ matrix in which $a_{ij}=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if}\quad j=i+1 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, then the least integer $k$ such that $A^k=0$ is ................

I tried to use the property that a maximum rank of a nilpotent matrix is $n/2$ where $n$ is the index. But can't get the answer.  Please help. Please also note that I don't know anything about Sylvester inequality so please don't include that in your answer...

Comment: Have you tried for smaller matrices? Like 2x2 and 3x3?

Comment: Have you looked at smaller examples and tried multiplying them out to look at $A^2$ and $A^3$?  Can you make a conjecture as to the pattern?  Can you prove your conjecture?  E.g. if this was a $4\times 4$ matrix instead, it would be $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  What does $A^2$ look like?  $A^3$? $A^4$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.